# How to get code from python functions

Tags: function, python-2.7

For example I have a code:

```
f = open('ifyouwantme', 'r')

while True:
   line = f.readline()
   if not line: break
```

And I want to see the code which is behind open and readline functions. How can I see it?

Answer (score 3):

You can download full source for Python from http://www.python.org/download/releases/ and see any implementation details you like.